# How do I make style corrections to the Bootstrap-DateTimePicker Calendar Widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I have implemented the Bootstrap-DatTimePicker located [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

I have chosen the "Minimum Setup" which you can see working properly [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

However, My implementation is not displaying with the correct calendar styling. You can see the Calendar display error in this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lqqu2s7/1/)

If you look closely at my implementation, upon clicking on the glyphicon calendar drop down, the calendar has a border table display and bleeds beyond the edge of the modal off to the right.

At first I thought I wasn't including all of the correct dependencies, but on double checking and ensuring I had them all listed correctly, it still has no effect.

Here are the **dependencies** I have:

```
<!-- Bootstrap & Core CSS (DPL) -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zerodevx/zero-md/v0.2.0/build/zero-md.html">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zerodevx/zero-md/v0.2.0/markdown-themes/default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zerodevx/zero-md/v0.2.0/highlight-themes/default.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/orion/ccdd.css">

<!-- Bootstrap, Custom, & Core jQuery Plugins DPL -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>  <!-- NEW *** Maybe Autocomplete???-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> <!-- NEW -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script> <!-- NEW -->
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/v0.7.15/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
```

I am trying to figure out how to correctly display the style of the calendar modal as per the Bootstrap-DateTimePicker example for a minimum setup.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Remove your custom CSS (or everything related to table, tbody, td, tr styling) from the fiddle and the calendar will look alright. There's conflict between your CSS and DateTimePicker CSS. You should try to be more specific with your classes selectors to avoid that kind of conflict.

Comment: Thanks i will try that.

Comment: Make sure that in your custom CSS you dont overwrite any of the styles defined by datetimepicker

Comment: Jonathan Anctil Do you wanna put that down as an answer so I can upvote you??? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already used the Web Inspector tool with your browser, I highly suggest it. Just navigate to the element and view the style properties being placed on it. Then you can add your own to override ones that are causing conflicts with your own in-line CSS or a CSS file.